# Indexing big documents into Elasticsearch from Spark

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I am using the es-hadoop connector to write RDDs directly into Elasticsearch. For small documents I never had any problems. But now I started indexing pdf files. I extract metadata and raw text and build a map out of these fields. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
val fileData = sc.binaryFiles(inputPath)
                 .map(f => myFunc(f, extraData))
                 .filter(f => !f.isEmpty).cache
                 .saveToEs("/" + index + "/" + docName)
```

I tried this with 5 rather small pdf's, between 100kb and 1mb. For the future I plan to index files of arbitray size (although only raw text is extracted). So even a 10mb or 100mb file should index without errors. But even with the small subset I get this error:

```
ERROR NetworkClient: Node [Connection refused] failed (:9200); selected next node
```

I looked into increasing `es.batch.size.bytes` but without success so far.

Am I missing other settings or how can I set up my cluster not to throw errors for indexing rather big documents?

Edit: I am running ES 2.1 on one node, 5 shards, 1 replica. The connector is elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2.0-m1 and Spark is in version 1.5.1.

Comment: Not sure it would help, but I would remove `.cache` from this chain and try again. `cache` method returns `DataFrame.this.type`, and not a `DataFrame`

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem in the original code which is a bit more complex. Actually I create multiple new RDDs from filters on the cached one and send these new RDDs to Elasticsearch. I just tried it and the error persists. But from what I see, the document is indexed sucessfully nevertheless. Still I want to fully understand the error and fix it.